# Removing residual office 2010 and 2016 components, icons, etc

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016, microsoft-office-2010, microsoft-office-2019

I installed Office 2019 HB while Outlook 2016 was still open (I know, bad move).  The installation went fine, but now I have remnants of Word 2010, Excel 2010, and Outlook 2016 in the Start menu, and Office14, Office15 folders all over the place.  None of the old Office apps appear in the Control Panel, and Revo Unininstaller doesn't find anything, either.  I downloaded and ran the Microsoft Support and Recovery Assistant, which "repaired" Office 2019, but otherwise did nothing.  How do I get rid of all these old files and clean up the Start Menu, etc.?

Any help will be appreciated.

Forgot to mention that I did try to uninstall Office 2010 and Outlook 2106, but the uninstall failed.

Comment: Completely uninstall Office 2019. Then restart. Then look Program Files and Program FIles (x86) for Microsoft Office (check anything like this). Then check Program Data. Remove all traces like this. Restart again and install Office 2019 fully. See if that fixes your issue.

Comment: Use [Revo Uninstaller Free](https://www.revouninstaller.com/products/revo-uninstaller-free/), then run the [Office uninstall support tool](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/uninstall-office-from-a-pc-9dd49b83-264a-477a-8fcc-2fdf5dbf61d8). Finally, install Office 2019.

Comment: Office 2016 and Office 2019 can both be installed on the same machine.  Why do you believe having office open when you were installing the newer version to be a bad thing?  You already had 2010 and 2016 installed when you installed 2019?  Your question is confusing with regards to that.  You can  [edit] your question to clarify it

Comment: Ramhound: regardless, I still have an Outlook 2016, Excel 2010, and Word 2010 icons in the Start menu, even though the uninstaller doesn't find anything except the Office 2019 installation.  Even the Office uninstall support tool didn't find any of the leftovers described.

Answer (score 3):

The [Office Uninstall Tool](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/uninstall-office-from-a-pc-9dd49b83-264a-477a-8fcc-2fdf5dbf61d8) is the correct (and best) way to remove MS Office software and remnants.

However, note that it will remove ALL Office products and files currently on your system, including Office 2019. So your process will be to run the Office Uninstall Tool, and then reinstall Office 2019.

Comment: I tried it, and it didn't find anything other than the Office 2019 installation.  Should I use it to uninstall 2019 as well?

Comment: I installed Open Shell and deleted the items from the All Programs list in the Win 7 format.  That seems to have done the job also for the Win 10 Start menu.  Thanks to all who commented.

Comment: Glad to see your issue has been resolved, in order to close this thread normally, it's suggested to mark the helpful post or your solution to answer, which would benefit others who also has similar issues.